# Can you change Added By information via a profile?

Tags: civicontribute, profile, activities

5.21.1 D7

Is it possible to change who added an activity/contribution - someone was logged in as someone else and well - its been an internal problem to say the least. I am being asked to change the Added By to the correct person.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can add source contact in profile field and do a bulk update. The options i can think of

1. Run sql query to update contact_id in civicrm_activity_contact table for record_type_id = source.
2. Or Export the activities you want to update and import them back with adding source contact id column in the csv file.

Thanks

Pradeep